# How can i add to the timer control a propert to display only hours minutes seconds without milliseconds?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the control designer i have label1.
In the designer the label text is set to: "00:00:00:000"

Then the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace WinFormsUI
{
    public partial class TimerControl : UserControl
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        public TimerControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Start();
        }


        public void Start()
        {
            timer1.Start();
            sw.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            sw.Reset();
            label1.Text = "00:00:00:000";
        }

        public void NoMsSecMin()
        {

        }

        private void TimerControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan elapsed = sw.Elapsed;
            label1.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}",
                          Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours),elapsed.Minutes,elapsed.Seconds,
                                     elapsed.Milliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

I added now the method NoMsSecMin
Maybe there is a better way, I want to add a property like Start Stop Reset something that i can easy set if to show or not milliseconds or seconds or minutes.

How can i make it so i will be able to select with this method what not to show or to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function like that?

```
ShowWhatIWant(true, false, false);

private string ShowWhatIWant(bool showMinutes, bool showSeconds, bool showMiliSeconds)
{
    string text = string.Format("{0:00}", Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours));

    if(showMinutes)
    {
        text += string.Format(":{0:00}", elapsed.Minutes);
    }

    if(showSeconds)
    {
        text += string.Format(":{0:00}", elapsed.Seconds);
    }

    if(showMiliSeconds)
    {
        text += string.Format(":{0:00}", elapsed.Milliseconds);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Comment: `ShowWhatIWant(true, false, true)` gives fun results